# Can What-If Questions Be Allowed in Universe Factory?

Tags: discussion, questions, blog, closed-questions

Throughout its conception, the blogs on Universe Factory were either interviews, story chapters and worldbuilding dos and don'ts.  But not once did I see a blog being a what-if question.  ([The last paragraphs of Great Lakes Earth's geography and solar systems are intended to be what-if questions in a more formal disguise.](https://medium.com/universe-factory/great-lakes-earth-geography-372bce96d642#.e9g78y1cd)  [However, I may not have made them obvious enough.](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-solar-system-of-great-lakes-earth-1ac15b6c439d#.hli77a59u))

So my question is this--can simple what-if questions, particularly those you asked on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange without much success, be allowed in Universe Factory?

Answer (score 2):

There have been two "what if?" posts so far:

[What if...the world was round?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-if-the-world-was-round-65df1645cc0c#.lbg16qxdt)

[What if...the moon was another earth?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-if-the-moon-was-another-earth-afb635c4c321#.f9iagzb9y)

An important characteristic of these posts is that they explore an idea; they don't *just* ask the question but also discuss possible answers and approaches.  Think of it not like the what-if question you can't ask on SE, but rather the what-if question *and its answers* that you can't ask on SE.

More posts like these are quite welcome.